# Symfony2 link a new Entity to an existing Entity without editing the existing Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an app called EC-cube running on top of Symfony 2.7.9.

My task is to add "features" to that App but **NOT** touch existing code.
What I can do is create new elements (Entities, Controllers) or hook to them through some events provided.

The thing I want to do is add some fields to existing entities. For that matter I created an Entity to contain the new data and it is mapped by primary key to the original Entity => I have 2 tables.

### What I managed

I managed to display new fields in the form through "hooks" by adding my Form Type to the original formBuilder I receive as argument in my event method.

Works great, one the form is sent, I have another event set up to receive the form data and update/save my Entity.

### More in context

Existing Entity: Customer

Extended Entity: MyCustomer

New Entity: UserCustom (where new fields are added).

Here are the Entities:

```
class MyCustomer extends Customer {
    // no changes, I just want a new name to use the regarding YML file to add a relation
}

class UserCustom extends \Eccube\Entity\AbstractEntity {

    private $id;

    private $dog_name;

    // other things and setters/getters
    // ...
}
```

And the `cdm.yml` files

For extending the existing Customer Entity:

```
Plugin\UserCustom\Entity\MyCustomer:
type: entity
table: dtb_customer # that table already exists
# I removed all columns definition in that file and just customized the repo and added the relation I want
repositoryClass: Plugin\UserCustom\Repository\MyCustomerRepository
oneToOne:
    Details:
        targetEntity: Plugin\UserCustom\Entity\UserCustom
        joinColumn:
            name: customer_id
            referencedColumnName: customer_id
```

The one to one relation is the critical point here.

For the new data:

```
Plugin\UserCustom\Entity\UserCustom:
type: entity
table: plg_user_custom
repositoryClass: Plugin\UserCustom\Repository\UserCustomRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        id: true
        column: customer_id
        generator:
            strategy: NONE
fields:
    dog_name:
        type: text
        nullable: true
    mailmaga:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I could then override the Customer entity in the Pimple with MyCustomer, and I added some logic to the repository related to it (MyCustomerRepository).
It works great.

### What is not working

Well the logic is working as I want, but I can't migrate (migrate:diff etc...) because the table `dtb_customer` exists for 2 entities: `Customer` and `MyCustomer`.

What can I do about that? The simplest idea is to make the existing table ignored by the migrations.

For now I edit tables by hand, but it's so error prone, not good I think.

---

I am no master in Symfony and that seems overwhelming to me hence my question that might sound easy or even irrelevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either do mapping by yml OR by annotations. So you dont need both.

Then the line `$app['eccube.repository.customer']->getQueryBuilderBySearchData($searchData);` seems to be a pimple container. Not symfonys DIC.

To solve you problem you should try to extend the original repository class with customs joins where needed and inject that class as `$app['eccube.repository.customer']` . This means, you would not touch the controller code. Just override the `getQueryBuilderBySearchData()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I discovered I need the 2 files.
But one problem is left, I can't apply migrations because the Class I extended (I don't change the fields) uses the same table.
The migration commands complain that a table already exists. Is there a way to "skip" that table (I'd like it to be totally ignored).